# SQL isNull is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sentence similar to this one:

```
SELECT ISNULL(sum(PARTE.AFECTADO_ENP_ARBOLADO),0) arbolado 
FROM INCENDIO
```

And I don't know how to work with `IsNull` because this is returning some field with null value.

Comment: If the table has no rows, then it will return a `NULL` value.

Comment: Do you mean to exclude null values? If yes, use where clause for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(PARTE.AFECTADO_ENP_ARBOLADO,0),0) arbolado FROM INCENDIO
```

Initially it will IS NULL will look for values and then it will Aggregate those values

Comment: This won't have any effect, even if you fix the syntax.

Comment: As Gordon wrote - this will not effect the result. sum ignores null values, so it's basically treating them as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(PARTE.AFECTADO_ENP_ARBOLADO,0)) as Arbolado FROM INCENDIO
```

Comment: You have corrected a syntax error on @mohan111's answer. Only issue is that it still returns null

Comment: can you please paste a data hear. so, we can help you.